# extract timecode seperated by a pattern and the text in the line after

Tags: regex

I want to extract the start-time and end-time and subtitle text from a set subtitle file. What is a better way of doing this? The subtitle file is as follows:

```
1
00:00:14,680 --> 00:00:23,960
on

2
00:00:24,480 --> 00:00:30,000
VERT

3
00:00:30,080 --> 00:00:38,120
UD

4
00:00:38,120 --> 00:00:39,040
REST
```

I want the following:

```
00:00:14.680 , 00:00:23.960, on
00:00:24.480 , 00:00:30.000, VERT
00:00:30.080 , 00:00:38.120, UD
00:00:38.120 , 00:00:39.040, REST
```

After some googling, I can extract on an online regex with the following, as shown in the image.  How do I put extracted text in a file (and replace the `,` with a `.`?

```
(\d.{11})\s-->\s(\d.{11})[\r\n](\w+)
```

[image]

**Update:**  Got what I want with the following. Is there any way to add to replace the ,\ with .?

```
gawk 'match($0, /([0-9].{11})\s-->\s([0-9].{11})/, a) {getline; print a[1], "\t", a[2],"\t", $0}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works using grep and perl:

```
$ cat text.txt | egrep -v '^[0-9]*$'| perl -pe 's/(:\d{2}),(\d)/$1.$2/g; s/ *--> */, /; s/(\d)\n/$1, /g;'
00:00:14.680, 00:00:23.960, on
00:00:24.480, 00:00:30.000, VERT
00:00:30.080, 00:00:38.120, UD
00:00:38.120, 00:00:39.040, REST
```

- the `egrep` removes empty and digits only lines
- several `perl` search & replaces fix the commas to a dots, fix the `-->` arrow to a comma, and joins tow lines with a comma

Comment: Do not know why it adds `1,` in the first line with the real `.srt` file. But not a big deal, everything else is extracted fine.

Comment: Not sure why. I tested your example input text, and it works properly on my system